# In laravel Api trying to get the property of non object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I am making api of create venues 
The issue i am facing is that there are two users 
1- Venue owner
2- user 
and what i want that i want to get the user_id which will create the venue but i cannot get the user_id in my venues table in database

My controller is

```
        $venue = new Venue($request->all());
        $venue->user_id = Auth::user()->user_id;
        $venue->save();

        $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Venue created Successfully!', 'dataArray' => $venue];
```

In line second where i wrote Auth::user()->user_id; it says trying to get the property of non object i did not inlcude the middlewarre but when i include it perfectly worked fine but i dont want to use middleware i want to get the user_id without middleware. 
Help me !!!

Comment: What middleware did you use that made it work?

Answer (score 1):

You're most probably getting this error because you're executing this code as not authenticated user. **Auth::user()** returns **NULL** in such cases, hence the error.

Comment: But when i include middleware it works perfectlt fine and returns me the user id why this is happening?

Comment: My routes is Route::post('',['uses' => 'VenuesController@registerVenue']); when i include middleware in this like Route::post('',['uses' => 'VenuesController@registerVenue','middleware'=>'simpleauth']); it works perfectly

Comment: i want to work without this midddleware and then give me trying to get the property of non object as i mentioned above

Comment: This middleware authorizes user - that's why it doesn't work without it. You need that middleware in order to be able to fetch current user from Auth.